# Convert USD into GPB using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I Need to convert currency (USD into GPB) using XSLT.

Actual exchange rates does not matter at this moment. 
(for example it is 1.35 USD for GBP)

Here is example of my XML:

```
<prices>
    <price mutable="true" packageRate="false">

        <totalPrice currencyCode="USD" fairPricesIncluded="false" groupDiscountAmount="0.00">88.30</totalPrice>

        <dates>
            <date>                
                <dailyPrice currencyCode="USD" fairPrice="false" priceChangeDate="2014-02-26" priceType="1">44.15</dailyPrice>                
            </date>
            <date>                
                <dailyPrice currencyCode="USD" fairPrice="false" priceChangeDate="2014-02-26" priceType="1">65.70</dailyPrice>                
            </date>
        </dates>

    </price>
</prices>
```

here is xslt I wrote to get the values I need:

```
<table>
    <xsl:for-each select="prices/price/dates/date">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="dailyPrice/@currencyCode"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="dailyPrice"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>

<table>
    <xsl:for-each select="prices/price">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="totalPrice/@currencyCode"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="totalPrice"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

so what is the right way to transform xml via xslt to get GBP instead of USD and to get a new values of totalPrice and dailyPrice elements according to exchange rate (1.35)?

expected output is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="currency" select="'GBP'"/>
<xsl:param name="rate" select="1.35"/>

<xsl:template match="/prices">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Prices</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="price/dates/date">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$currency"/>
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(dailyPrice * $rate, '0.00')"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each> 
        <tr>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$currency"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(price/totalPrice * $rate, '0.00')"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this will return:

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <th>Prices</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>GBP 59.60</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>GBP 88.70</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>Total</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>GBP 119.20</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

rendered:

[image]